# Cannot Browse in sql to backup bak file

Tags: sql-server

As the title says I cannot browse and cannot see backup folder.

[image]

is there any other way to restore bak file ? or how can I fix this ?

Comment: Write query for restore data.

Comment: Probably you have no permission on the folder...

Comment: trying to give a permission

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
RESTORE DATABASE Databasename
   FROM DISK = 'Z:\SQLServerBackups\tms.bak' ;
```

Comment: it says access is denied and also RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Comment: It is not problem to sql server. Your path is not access to you. it is os issue. like permission issue

Answer (score 0):

The backup runs with the file permissions of the id running SQL Server. So, you need to either:

1. Move the file to a location SQL Server has access to. The default backup location is always a safe bet.
2. Grant permissions to the account running SQL to see the file.

If using a mapped drive, this is more difficult. First, the mapping won't apply so use a fully qualified path name (e.g. \server\path\backupfile.bak) instead of the drive letter. Second, make sure the permissions are correct.

Comment: I try default backup location but then it says The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: Have you checked the file permissions?

Comment: well I was having file permisson when I tried it from desktop so as you said I moved to default location and I dont get permisson error. but I think I should write it UNC path. I was trying this C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\YeniKumbara.bak and got Operating system error 3

Comment: I'm guessing this is a remote SQL Server instance. If so, you need to put the file in the default backup folder for that instance. Or, use a UNC path that the remote server has access to.